# How do I do a jQuery load without a query string and arguments?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a dumb network device that has limited HTTP hosting capabilities and I'm trying to write a slightly more dynamic page to display data with.  A some current process values can be found in plain-text at `/temp.dat` on the device, but my stone-simple jQuery script...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $('#temp').load('/temp.dat');
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
      $('#temp').load('/temp.dat');
   }, 2000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});
```

...seems to endlessly fail (only after the first `.load` on the initial page load) because the device abhors HTML query parameters.  Chrome's JS console shows endless errors like the following:

```
GET http://192.168.1.250/temp.dat?_=1341980712854
```

How can  I get jQuery (or pure JavaScript) to hammer away at a specific URL without attaching the HTML query (...`?_=123456789`)?

Comment: "Setting cache to false also appends a query string parameter, "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL." http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to add this at the top of the script

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    cache: true
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when console outputs `GET http://192.168.1.250/temp.dat?_=1341980712854`, thats not an error, thats the log of the attempt to perform that task. When its colored red, it means that the HTTP GET of that particular address returned an error (like a 500).

Comment: Yes, but it's erroring out because it's attaching the query string (the `?_=...`) which the device cannot handle.  If that wasn't there, it shouldn't happen